# XML serialization of a member using an abstract class using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, attributes, xml-serialization

I am having trouble with XML serialization for members that use generics. The following is what my basic class structure looks like (and I want to use the default XML serialization, not overload IXmlSerializable in every class):

```
public class MyClassToSerialize
{
    public Problem<int> Problem;
}

public class MyOtherClassToSerialize
{
    public Problem<string> Problem;
}

public abstract class Problem<T>
{
}

public class ProblemImplementationOne<T> : Problem<T>
{
}

public class ProblemImplementationTwo<T> : Problem<T>
{
}
```

Now here is what I tried:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationOne<T>))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationTwo<T>))]
public abstract class Problem<T>
{
}
```

This doesn't work: it gives a compile error on the `<T>` parameter used in the attributes. The following (obviously) doesn't work as well, because it doesn't give enough information for serializing:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationOne<>))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationTwo<>))]
public abstract class Problem<T>
{
}
```

This gives the error at serializing: "Generic type definition cannot be used in serialization. Only specific generic types can be used."

Does anyone know an easy solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, depending on the actual runtime type of the `Problem` properties in the objects you're serializing:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationOne<int>))] 
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationTwo<int>))] 
public class MyClassToSerialize 
{ 
    public Problem<int> Problem; 
} 

[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationOne<string>))] 
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProblemImplementationTwo<string>))] 
public class MyOtherClassToSerialize 
{ 
    public Problem<string> Problem; 
}
```